# Debugging strapi in Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, strapi

I'm trying to debug my strapi project (3.0.0 beta 16.6) in VS Code.
My launch.json:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach to strapi",
  "port": 9229
}
```

My package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "debug": "node --inspect=127.0.0.1:9229 ./node_modules/strapi/bin/strapi.js develop"
}
```

Debugger attaches to the process, but all my breakpoints become unverified (appear black, not red). What's wrong with my configs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this answer come from the following [strapi/strapi issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3743#issuecomment-519583569):

I have come up with next solution:
having next script in server.js file (my custom one):

```
const strapi = require('strapi');
strapi({ dir: process.cwd(), autoReload: true }).start();
```

I'm using nodemon by next command: `nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9228 server.js`

Now I can attach to `9228` by debugger.

Comment: Thank you! I got even more than I expected. Bonus: autoreload.

Answer (score 11):

Add VS configuration "NODE: launch via npm" in `.vscode/launch.json` `"configurations"` property and run

```json
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch via NPM",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run-script",
        "develop"
      ],
      "port": 9229,
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
```

Comment: Confirmed with Strapi 14.1.6, but I missing console output so I added `"console": "integratedTerminal"`

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to @alxnkt comment. 
I have encountered the same and solved it by changing the launch.json to port 9230

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach to strapi",
  "port": 9230
}
```

while keeping the port on package.json as 9229

```
"debug": "node --inspect=127.0.0.1:9229 ./node_modules/strapi/bin/strapi.js develop"
```

There are somehow 2 processes running when calling the Strapi develop command (possibly the admin panel and its core server), the process we have to monitor becomes port 9230 instead.

Comment: In my case the port is incrementing by 1 everytime I change some file in Strapi project because then Strapi restarts the server and the second process, I believe. This makes it very annoying to debug it...

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me using Strapi v4

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
     {
      "name": "STRAPI Debug",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "node",
      "runtimeVersion":"14.19.0",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--lazy"],
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js",
      "args": [
        "develop"
      ],
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
     },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For strapi v4 you will have to add `"sourceMap": true` to `compilerOptions` of  `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: This should be accepted. Shame strapi starter doesnt add this property ! thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `NODE_OPTIONS`:

```sh
NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' yarn strapi develop
```

You'll get:

```sh
$ NODE_OPTIONS="--inspect" yarn strapi develop
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/8564942a-6476-443a-9f64-87fa6d0055b7
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
yarn run v1.22.5
$ strapi develop
Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9229 failed: address already in use
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9230/7da840dd-cb89-493f-8ce0-e11530efdfbb
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

Now you can use *Debug: Attach to Node Process* to attach to port 9230.

Comment: Confirmed with Strapi 4.1.6

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved by setting port number to 9203:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach to strapi",
  "port": 9229
}
```

But I have no idea about HOW it works...

Answer (score 1):

I just launched it via NPM, here is my launch.json (in .vscode folder)

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch via NPM",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run-script",
        "develop"
      ],
      "port": 9229,
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Confirmed with Strapi 14.1.6, but I missing console output so I added `"console": "integratedTerminal"`