# Debugging a strapi plugin

Tags: debugging, plugins, breakpoints, strapi

How do I setup vscode to debug a strapi plugin with breakpoints?

The plugin works, but I cannot set breakpoints or trace through my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to start Strapi:

```
node --inspect "./node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js" develop
```

Then, in VSCode:

- Open the Run view
- Select 'Attach' from the Run and Debug dropdown, at the top
- Click the green Play button
- You can now set breakpoints on your code and execution will stop on them

For other options, see question: [Debugging strapi in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58145392/debugging-strapi-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

This is for Typescript project:
src/plugins/[plugin]/tsconfig.server.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true // enable source map
}
```

src/admin/webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = (config, webpack) => {
    config.devtool = "source-map";
    return config;
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true // enable source map
}
```

.vscode/launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Strapi Plugin",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:1337/admin",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMaps": true
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Strapi",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "develop"],
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "preLaunchTask": "build plugin", // rebuild for server side code
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "(https?://.+/)",
                "action": "startDebugging",
                "name": "Debug Strapi Plugin"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

.vscode/task.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build plugin",
            "command": "cd ./src/plugins/[plugin] && npm run build", // 
            "type": "shell"
        }
    ]
}
```

change [plugin] to your plugin name, and select "Debug Strapi" as startup session in vscode.